# What tool to tighten this nut?

Tags: plumbing, tools

[image]This is on a valve for a fancy walk in tub.  The nut tightens it against the top of the tub to hold it in place.

But I have no idea what this kind of nut is called, nor what tool to use to properly tighten it.  I can get it kind of tight using vice grips, normal wrenches, and hammering it with a flat head screwdriver.

Some of them are about 2 inches in diameter, others 2.5-3 inches.

But surely there is a proper tool for this?  What's it called?

Comment: I've always just used a slotted screwdriver and the palm of my other hand. Works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For slotted collet nuts I use either an adjustable or slotted spanner wrench.
[image: Spanner Wrench]
[image: Slotted Wrench]
[image: Adjustable Spanner]

Answer (score 4):

Although you can nearly always use *something* from a normal toolbox, a *hook spanner* is ideal. One of the top two in this image would work (the third is a pin spanner):
[image: Spanners via ja.wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

The usual procedure is to [use a slotted screwdriver against the tabs](https://www.google.com/patents/US5374785), and strike lightly with a hammer or mallet.

[image: source USPTO US5374785]